# JavaScript null property error on separate HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I have a couple of HTML pages all linked to the same JavaScript file (which contains a number of IIFE functions).
One of the functions controls a certain button that is only on one page. But since the other HTML files are connected to the same JS file, on them pages I get console error:

[image: Error Message]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
at showDivs (scripts.js:99)
at scripts.js:82
at scripts.js:108
```

So how should I handle the function so that only if it detects element, it should apply the style?

```
(function(){

let left = document.getElementById("left");
let right = document.getElementById("right");

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
};


left.addEventListener("click", plusDivs(-1));
right.addEventListener("click", plusDivs(1));

})();
```

The error is on the line: x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

I have already tried putting in 'if x exists, then do the above', but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Please paste the content of the error as quoted text, not an image to it.

Comment: Please check the value of slideIndex and length of x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line before the line that causes the error:

```
if(x[slideIndex - 1])
```

to check if the element you are trying to get exists. Checking if the array exists will have no efect in yours case because the array exists. You want to know if the element is in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the **function reference** instead of **result of function invocation**

Wrap your existing `left` and `right`'s `addEventListener`'s in a function

```
left.addEventListener("click", function(){ plusDivs(-1) });
right.addEventListener("click", function(){ plusDivs(1) } );
```

Comment: Yes, makes sense but that is not the issue

Comment: @mts396 really? Can you share a working snippet demonstrating using `<>` the issue?

Comment: Sorry @gurvinder372 , what I mean is the code you have included is correct, and it works, but that is not the issue for the problem I have. For me the issue is that the HTML files which do not contain that element (x) display an error as they reference the same JS file. So I wanted to find out how that can be avoided. I could add a JSFiddle but that would mean I have to put in separate HTML files to demonstrate the issue.